# Newbie - customer profiling in Python (pandas) using loc()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm a newbie, so please excuse me if I use incorrect terms. I have a df with customer purchasing info and customers are identified by a unique user_id. Each item a user_id buys in each transaction creates a new row (if a customer buys 5 products in 1 transaction, 5 different rows are created with that products info).

I have created customer profiles based on 4 variables (income, age, dept id & parental status) using the loc function. It has worked, however, the outcome isn't what I want. There are 106,143 customers in the df and 30,964,564 rows. The profiles I created (young parent, young single adult, higher earner, over 60, other ['other' to catch anything not assigned one of the other profiles]) are being assigned to each row, rather than to each user_id e.g. user_id 1 buys 5 items, 1 of which matches the conditions of 'young parent', the rest are assigned 'other'. This is my code:

```
# create flag for 'High earner' (age: 40-59, income: 400000+, department_id: 1, 4, 7, 19, 16, parental_status: Parent)

final_df.loc[(final_df['age_range'].isin(['40-49', '50-59'])) & (final_df['income'] >= 400000) & (final_df['department_id'].isin([1, 4, 7, 19, 16])) & (final_df['parental_status'] == 'Parent'), 'customer_profile'] = 'Higher earner'
```

```
# create flag for 'Young single adult' (age: <39, income: <=199999, department_id: 1, 4, 7, 19, parental_status: Non-parent)

final_df.loc[(final_df['age'] <= 39) & (final_df['income'] <= 199999) & (final_df['department_id'].isin([1, 4, 7, 19])) & (final_df['parental_status'] == 'Non-parent'), 'customer_profile'] = 'Young single adult'
```

```
# create flag for 'Young parent' (age: 20-39, income: <=199999, department_id: 4, 13, 16, 17, 18 parental_status: Parent)

final_df.loc[(final_df['age_range'].isin(['20-29', '30-39'])) & (final_df['income'] <= 199999) & (final_df['department_id'].isin([4, 13, 16, 17, 18])) & (final_df['parental_status'] == 'Parent'), 'customer_profile'] = 'Young parent'
```

```
# create flag for 'Over 60' (age: 60+, income: <=199999, department_id: 1, 4, 11, 12, 15, 20 parental_status: Parent)

final_df.loc[(final_df['age'] >= 60) & (final_df['income'] <= 199999) & (final_df['department_id'].isin([1, 4, 11, 12, 15, 20])) & (final_df['parental_status'] == 'Parent'), 'customer_profile'] = 'Over 60'
```

```
# impute all NaN values as 'Other'

final_df['customer_profile'].fillna('Other', inplace=True)
```

This is the result:

```
    user_id customer_profile
0   1   Other
1   1   Other
2   1   Other
3   1   Other
4   1   Other
5   1   Other
6   1   Other
7   1   Other
8   1   Other
9   1   Other
10  1   Young parent
11  1   Other
12  1   Other
13  1   Other
14  1   Other
15  1   Other
16  1   Other
17  1   Other
18  1   Other
19  1   Other
20  1   Other
21  1   Other
22  1   Other
23  1   Young parent
24  1   Young parent
```

What I actually want is, "if 'young parent' (or any profile) is assigned even once to a user_id, then all 'other' for that user_id must be changed to 'young parent' too" (a customer cannot have 2 profiles!). So, the above results should show 'young parent' in each row.

Is this possible? Am I using the wrong function? My knowledge is limited and any advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html) the `Other` values in the `customer_profile` column, then [`group`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.groupby.html) the column by `user_id` and [`transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.transform.html) with [`first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html) to select the first non-nan value per `user_id`

```
m = df['customer_profile'].eq('Other')
df['customer_profile'] = df['customer_profile'].mask(m)\
                            .groupby(df['user_id']).transform('first')
```

To further simplify this you can skip the final step in your code where you are using `fillna` to fill the `Other` values because to use groupby we have to mask this values back to `NaN`. So `fillna` is a redundant step.

```
df['customer_profile'] = df.groupby('user_id')['customer_profile'].transform('first')
```

---

```
    user_id customer_profile
0         1     Young parent
1         1     Young parent
2         1     Young parent
3         1     Young parent
4         1     Young parent
5         1     Young parent
6         1     Young parent
7         1     Young parent
...
23        1     Young parent
24        1     Young parent
```

Comment: Thanks @shubham this worked for me. Just confirming, because fillna is redundant, then in the solution .eq('Other') should actually be .eq('NaN')?

Comment: We don't have to use `eq` in that case..You can directly use `df['customer_profile'] = df.groupby('user_id')['customer_profile'].transform('first')` to get the desired result.